# vue js audio duration not getting reset

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a problem with my music player that im making. the issue is when i set the current time of my audio it just gets reset and doesnt set the time to what i said. these are my codes:

audio and slider:

```
<audio class="podcast col-12"></audio>

<q-slider
  class="slider col-10"
  v-model="slider"
  @change="setTime"
  @pan="podPause"
  :min="0"
  :max="1"
  :step="0"
  color="orange-4"
 />
```

and these are the scripts:

```
function fmtTime(current) {
      var houres = Math.floor(current / 360);
      var minutes = Math.floor((current - houres * 60) / 60);
      var seconds = Math.floor(current - minutes * 60);
      var x = houres < 10 ? "0" + houres : houres;
      var y = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      var z = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      if (x < 10) {
        return y + ":" + z;
      } else {
        return x + ":" + y + ":" + z;
      }
    }

    function setTime(value) {
      console.log("Audio Duration: " + state.currentPod.duration);
      state.podPlayed = false;
      state.currentPod.pause();
      console.log("Setting up 'canplay' event listener...");

      state.currentPod.addEventListener("canplay", onCanPlay);

      onCanPlay(value);
    }

    function onCanPlay(value) {
      console.log("Audio is playable/loaded!");

      var duration = state.currentPod.duration;
      var time = value * duration;
      console.log("currentTime: " + state.currentPod.currentTime);

      state.currentPod.currentTime = time;
      slider.value = value;
      state.podOldTime = time;
      state.podCurrentTimeDisplay = fmtTime(time);
      state.currentPod.play();
      state.podPlayed = true;
    }
```

if you need more of my code please tell me and ill put it here. thanks!

i tried this function without onCanPlay function insite the setTime one and it didnt work and it just sets the currentTime of the audio to 0.

Comment: ill give it a try. thankyou